# Accessing function object's properties from inside the function body

Tags: javascript, function, properties

Functions in javascript is also an object and can have properties. So is there any way to access its properties from inside its own function body?

like this

```
var f = function() { 
  console.log(/*some way to access f.a*/);
};
f.a = 'Test';
f(); //should log 'Test' to console
```

Comment: Well, your example uses a reference, so you get the answers accordingly.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. Want a way to set f.a=3 from inside the body of function f. Here are two attempts that fail:function f()
 {
 f.a=3;
 this.a=3;
 } // f
console.log(f.a);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`arguments.callee`  is the function itself and doesn't get affected by the name of the function.

```
var f = function() { 
  console.log(arguments.callee.a);
};
f.a = 'Test';
f();
```

Comment: Great answer! I believe this is the cleanest approach. In torazaburo answer, binding the function to itself looses the reference of its parent when using 'this', and Christos answer doesn't work if the function doesn't have an identifier (i.e anonymous function)

Comment: However when using this approach in recursive ways, the value of 'this' will be different for each call, the first one will be the function's parent, the next ones would be the arguments property of the previous call, since we would be calling the function from arguments object, using arguments.callee, We would have to use arguments.callee.apply(this)!

Comment: But for the real purpose of this question, is indeed the best answer!

Comment: thank you!
btw I don't really understand your recursive calls point. can you make it clear?

Comment: Forget about it, it only becomes a problem if you use arguments.callee as a function and not as a reference to get a property in it, both things are different! For example: arguments.callee() calls the function f arguments.callee.a just get the property 'a' from f

Comment: If you use arguments.callee as a function i.e: arguments.callee(), the value of 'this' will be different from the original call, consider this function: `function f (recurse) {
    console.log('the value of this is: ', this);
    
    if (recurse) {
        arguments.callee(false);
    }
}

f(true);`

You will notice that the value of this is different in both calls!

Comment: In the first call, the value is the 'Window' object, in the second, the value is the 'arguments' object of the first call, because the second time you call the function _(via arguments.callee())_ you're calling a reference to the function f _(callee)_ that resides inside arguments object!

Comment: `arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode, because it prevent certain types of VM performance optimizations. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee and just call `f.a`

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical to access them using "this"?

Comment: @Siavoshkc `this` in javascript will normally point to the parent object or something else.

Answer (score 6):

The classic way to do this is to bind the function to itself, after which it can access its own properties via `this`:

```js
 var f = function() { 
   console.log(this.a);    // USE "THIS" TO ACCESS PROPERTY
 };

 f.a = 'Test';
 f = f.bind(f);            // BIND TO SELF

 f();                      // WILL LOG 'Test' TO CONSOLE
```

Comment: ILLUMINATI CONFIRMED

Answer (score 2):

You could just use this:

```
console.log(f.a);
```

If `f` is executed, `f()`, before `f.a = 'Test';` you will get `undefined` in the console, since there isn't any property with name/key `a` be defined. After `f.a = 'Test';` being executed, the name/key `a` will be defined on f and the corresponding value would be `'Test'`. Hence, executing later on the function `f`, the value  `'Test'` would be the output to the console.

Answer (score 1):

`Prototypes` is what you are looking for.

```
var F = function() {
    console.log(this.a);
}

F.prototype.a = 'Test';

// instantiate new Object of class F
new F();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but what i want to ask is to access properties of the function itself instead of properties of the prototype

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript Closures;

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

```
const add = (function () {
  let counter = 0;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();

add();
add();
add();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement a static variable, using the function itself as an Object:

```
function f()
    {
    if (!f.staticObj)
        f.staticObj={a:3};
    return f.staticObj;
    } // f
console.log(f().a); // Assigns the var
console.log(f().a); // Returns the var
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set this up using an IIFE:

```
var f = (function () {
  function f () {
    console.log(f.a);
  }
  f.a = 'Test';
  return f;
})();

f() // logs 'Test'
f.a === 'Test' // true
```

Note that you don't have to use `f` (or even a function declaration) for this to work properly:

```
var f = (function () {
  var _f = function () {
    console.log(_f.a);
  };
  _f.a = 'Test'
  return _f;
});

f() // logs 'Test'
f.a === 'Test' // true
```

Some people like to use the same variable throughout to emphasize that the inner `f` will eventually become the outer `f`, and some people prefer to distinguish each scope. Either way is fine.