# How to access an object outside when it is present in a named function

Tags: javascript

How to access an object outside of the function when it is present in a named function.

```
 function a(){
   var someobj = { b: "abc"} 
   console.log(someobj)
 }
```

I tried to set a variable and then access it but I get an error.

```js
var bla = function a() {
  var someobj = {
    b: "abc"
  }
  console.log(someobj)
}
console.log(bla().someobj)
```

Comment: Functions acts as objects . Here is another similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887281/accessing-function-objects-properties-from-inside-the-function-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a local variable and its scope is inside of that function.

Probably, your confusion is on how a function is called as a `constructor`.

```
new bla()
```

So, you can access properties from instantiated objects through a function called as a `constructor`.  Further, to set properties you need to use the context `this`.

```js
var bla = function a() {
  this.someobj = {b: "abc"};
//^^^^
//  console.log(someobj)
}
console.log(new bla().someobj)
//          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the object in your function.

Adding the "." after `bla()` without returning something is the same thing as `undefined.someobj`

```js
var bla = function a() {
  return {someobj:{
    b: "abc"
  }}
}
console.log(bla().someobj)
```